# Error Setting Rules with Twitter API v2: Client Forbidden Due to Lack of Project Association

Tags: python, twitter

I get this error:

```
{“client_id”:“…”,“detail”:“When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.”,“registration_url”:“…”,“title”:“Client Forbidden”,“required_enrollment”:“Appropriate Level of API Access”,“reason”:“client-not-enrolled”,“type”:“…”}
```

But:

It’s not a standalone app, it’s part of a project. I just want to use filtered streams to automatically get every new tweet of one specific twitter user.

here is the part of my code:

```
def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Methode für die Bearer Token Authentifizierung.
    """
    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {BEARER_TOKEN}"
    r.headers["User-Agent"] = "v2FilteredStreamPython"
    return r

def set_rules(headers, chat_id):
    rules = [{"value": f"from:{TWITTER_USERNAME}", "tag": f"Twitter stream for {TWITTER_USERNAME}"}]
    payload = {"add": rules}
    response = requests.post("https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules", auth=bearer_oauth, json=payload)
    if response.status_code != 201:
        message = f"Fehler beim Setzen der Regeln: {response.text}"
        updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
        return False
    return True

def start_twitter_stream(chat_id):
    if not set_rules(bearer_oauth, chat_id):
        return
    stream_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream"
    response = requests.get(stream_url, auth=bearer_oauth, stream=True)
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        if line:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            text = tweet.get('data', {}).get('text', '')
            message = f"{TWITTER_USERNAME} posted a new Tweet! Here is the Tweet:\n{text}"
            updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)
```

Did changes to get the code like in this example:

https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py